# One Table, One query, One form - Multiple users

Tags: ms-access-2007

I'm really new to Access and SQL so hopefully this is not a silly question, however I've been looking for two days without finding a solution to my problem.

Scenario: 
My db will  be located in a shared folder.
I have created a table (mytbl), a select query to this table(qrymytbl) with some simple critera... and finally a form (frmqrymytbl) bound to the query.

My aim is to load data into the table and then allow multiple users to input additional information via the form.

Problem One: 
So far I have been unable to restrict two users from selecting the same record.

Problem Two: 
I have created a command button on the form to Me.requery 'OnClick' which, when there is no record matching the query criteria, returns and enters a blank row into my table

No doubt these are just some of the issues I'm going to face along the way :)
Any help is greatly appreciated and if I am going about this all wrong I would be more than happy if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks
Na'te

Comment: Not a good idea. Split the database and give each person their own front-end http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/split-an-access-database-HA010342026.aspx

Comment: Have read up a little on this and it seems to be a better option. In saying that I still cant find the methodology that prevents the Form from finding the same records, even with multiple front-ends.

Comment: See also http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/set-options-for-a-shared-access-database-mdb-HP005188297.aspx

Comment: Ok so this has locked the records exactly as it should, stopping two users from being able to edit them which is great... but if the form could not open a locked record in the first place that would be even better. Is there anything built in to do this?

Comment: I am fairly sure there is nothing in DAO. You can role your own with a flag.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Remou that the built in lock is not very user-friendly. If you build your own locking mechanism, then at some point you need to be able to 'reset' a lock if the user 'goes to lunch/home' or crash. 
Without knowing what the application is intended to do and how the multiple users can interact with records, the next suggestion may seem crazy.
Are two different users 'supposed' to edit any given record, or only records they entered? If only supposed to edit their own, you could filter the form data they see based on either their Workstation name, or the user name they log into windows with.
Good Luck!